# Variadic number of dynamically allocated arrays

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, variadic-functions

I have a bunch of dynamically allocated arrays (scoped to the entire program):

```
double* Ux{nullptr};
Ux = (double*) fftw_malloc( sizeof(double) * dataSize);
```

which are usually initialized according to:

```
std::fill(Ux, Ux + dataSize, 0.);
```

I would like to define a function which takes an arbitrary number of arrays and dynamically allocate the requested amount of memory using the fftw_malloc. The purpose of this is to make the code more readable and simply allocate and initialize all the resources in one place. In the case of a single array, my solution is as follows:

```
template <typename T>
void alloc_fftw_array(const size_t& dataSize, T* &array)
{
    array = (T*) fftw_malloc( sizeof(T) * dataSize);

    std::fill(array, array + dataSize, static_cast<T>(0));
}
```

and

```
double* Ux{nullptr};
alloc_fftw_array(dataSize, Ux);
```

In the case of a variable number of arrays, I came up with something like

```
template <typename... T>
void alloc_fftw_array(const size_t& dataSize, T* &... array)
{
    ((array = (T*) = fftw_malloc( sizeof(T) * dataSize)), ...);
    
    ((std::fill(array, array + dataSize, static_cast<T>(0))), ...);
}
```

which results in

```
double* Ux{nullptr};
double* Uy{nullptr};
alloc_fftw_array(dataSize, Ux, Uy);
```

Is it there a better alternative to the above variadic function? Is it somehow possible to avoid these fold expressions?

Comment: What's the use-case for `alloc_fftw_array` allocating multiple arrays in one call, rather than calling it multiple times? Are you just curious how to make it work, or is there an underlying problem this is supposed to solve?

Comment: Why not wrap that in RAII class (potentially `std::unique_ptr`)?

Comment: Why using output argument instead of return?

Comment: @Some programmer dude Well, there are many arrays to be allocated and initialized which IMO makes the code less readable. As you pointed out, the reason for this is to allocate and initialize all of them in a single call. At this point the solution seems to work as expected, however, I would like to learn whether this is the right approach for solving such a task.

Comment: If the pointer is represented by a class that acts like a smart pointer, then you can have a vector or an array of smart pointers, avoiding the need for the function.

Comment: @Jarod42 No particular reason actually, I'm used to it. Isn't it a matter of taste in this case? Regarding your previous question, I'm not an experienced programmer, as you may anticipated, therefore at this point my options are limited. I will look into this.

Comment: I agree with @jarod42 - not quite what you asked but look into `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter (to call `fftw_free`).  You can then put these into a `std::vector` and they will be destroyed automatically when the vector goes out of scope.

Comment: Alternatively, you could gather them together in a struct or class and initialise them in the constructor.  Again, when the object containing them goes out of scope, they will be destroyed.

Comment: @PaulSanders sure Paul, that's one way to solve it but unless I'm not mistaken, I will still need a sort of a variadic constructor and probably a vector to store the pointers. The arrays I'm trying to elegantly allocate and initialize are scoped to the entire program.  In such a case, is there really any advantage of using custom class/struct or smart pointers over the aforementioned approach?

Comment: Ah well, if you don't include all the relevant information in the question, how can you expect a useful answer?

Comment: @PaulSanders well, to be honest I consider all of the those answers useful. I'm a self-taught programmer (still a beginner). Asking more experienced collegaues these questions is the only chance for me to learn programming the right way. I didn't mean to upset anyone, just tried to show the effort and ask for a piece of advice on how to enhance my coding skills.

Comment: Sure.  I'm not upset.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to take into account the suggestions provided in the comments, and eventually came up with the following wrapper class (still at the early stage of development, though):

```
template <class T__>
class ArrayFFTW
{
public:
    typedef T__            value_type;
    typedef T__*           pointer;
    typedef T__&           reference;
    typedef value_type*    iterator;
    typedef std::size_t    size_type;

    ArrayFFTW()
    { sResources__.push_back(this); }

    ArrayFFTW(const size_t& N)
    {
        allocate(N);
        
        sResources__.push_back(this);
    }

    ~ArrayFFTW()
    { fftw_free(this->pData__); this->pData__ = nullptr; }

    void
    allocate(const size_t& N)
    {
        this->pData__ = pointer (fftw_malloc(sizeof(value_type) * N));

        this->mSize = N;

        fill(static_cast<value_type>(0));
    }

    void
    fill(const value_type& initVal)
    { std::fill(this->begin(), this->end(), initVal); }

    iterator
    begin()
    { return iterator(std::__addressof(this->pData__[0])); }

    iterator
    end()
    { return iterator(std::__addressof(this->pData__[this->mSize])); }

    size_type
    size()
    { return this->mSize; }

    static void
    allocateResources(const size_t& N)
    {
        for (auto& array : sResources__)
        {
            if (array->pData__ == nullptr)
            {
                array->allocate(N);
            }
        }
    }

    reference
    operator[](const size_type& offset)
    { return pData__[offset]; }

    operator iterator()
    { return this->begin(); }

private:
    pointer pData__{nullptr};

    size_type mSize{0};

    static std::vector<ArrayFFTW<value_type>*> sResources__;
};

using fftw_array = ArrayFFTW<double>; // + other relevant aliases
```

Eventually, this reduces the somewhat tedious allocation/initialization of a large number of arrays to:

```
fftw_array arr1, arr2, arr3, ..., arrN;
fftw_array::allocateResources(dataSize);
```

Comment: See [Rule of 5/3/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).